# SQL injection - how to use preparedstatement in java

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sql-injection

i have a SQL which is dynamically build,the following is the query :

```
private String constructTownSearchQuery(String country, String stateName,String districtName,String townName) {
        StringBuilder statesSearchQuery = new StringBuilder();
        statesSearchQuery.append(" select cntry.countryid,cntry.country,sta.stateid,sta.state,dst.districtid,dst.district,twn.townid,twn.town ");
        statesSearchQuery.append(" from m_countries as cntry,m_states as sta,m_districts as dst,m_towns as twn ");
        statesSearchQuery.append(" where cntry.countryid = sta.countryid ");
        statesSearchQuery.append(" and sta.stateid = dst.stateid ");
        statesSearchQuery.append(" and twn.districtid=dst.districtid ");

        if (!country.equals("")) {
            statesSearchQuery.append(" and cntry.country='").append(country).append("' ");
        }
        if (!stateName.equals("")) {
            statesSearchQuery.append(" and sta.state='").append(stateName).append("'");
        }
        if (!districtName.equals("") ) {
           statesSearchQuery.append(" and dst.district='").append(districtName).append("'");
        }
        if (!townName.equals("") ) {
           statesSearchQuery.append(" and  twn.town='").append(townName).append("'");
        }
        statesSearchQuery.append(" order by cntry.country ");
        return statesSearchQuery.toString();
    }
```

when i used this query it is prone for SQL injection and i was told to use `PreparedStatement` to avoid this.

Pleas suggest me how to go about using `preparedStatement` for this.

Regards.

Comment: follow tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @JimGarrison, I have also used the preparedstatement but in my case it involves to construt query dynamic how to get this done is my question.

Comment: The people who have down voted are good, as they have not given any comment for doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add value parameter to query  like (`.append(country)`) this then it could be easily inject-able.

For Example if you pass country as `"Australia"` which is normal case it would not have any problem but if I pass country as `"a' or '1'='1"`, then it will select all your country.

Where as in a `PreparedStatement` SQL statement is precompiled and this object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times and you will be safe from SQL injection.

more on [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
String selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId = ? ";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
prepStmt.setString(1, userId);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

More on [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java).

Comment: thanks Quoi, I have already seen SWASP my problem is if i have one variable as you have show it is better to bind but i have multiple and while run time only i know what are the variable i get to construct query, so how to do this?

Comment: as you can create query on runtime, you can set value on runtime also but on condition

Comment: thanks for the response but it would really help me if you could provide some sample in your answer.

Comment: see you would construct your query like - `if (!country.equals("")) {
            statesSearchQuery.append(" and cntry.country=?");
        } and so on...` and your `PreparedStatement` would be - String selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId = ? ";
`PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement); 
if (!country.equals("")){ prepStmt.seString(country);}...`