# Error in inserting commands in SQL databases using java

Tags: java, sql

I need to update the sql database daily manner for changes in clicks impressions and conversions column. i had array for each column. In this statement there is a error . i cant find the error too.help please

```
for(int j=1;j<row;j++){
pst= conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO babum_test.l2ttracker SET Clientid='"+Customer_ID[j]+"',Accountname='"+Account[j]"',Dates='"Day[j]"',Clicks='"Clicks[j]"',Impressions='"Impressions[j]"',CTR='"CTR[j]"',Avg_CPC='"Avg_CPC[j]"',Cost='"Costs[j]"',Conversions='"Conversions[j]"',Converted_clicks='"Converted_clicks[j]"',Avg_position='"Avg_position[j]"',Revenue='"Total_Conv_value[j]+"' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'"+ "'Clicks='"+Clicks[j]"',Impressions='"Impressions[j]"',CTR='"CTR[j]"',Avg_CPC='"Avg_CPC[j]"',Cost='"Costs[j]"',Conversions='"Conversions[j]"',Avg_position='"Avg_position[j]"',Converted_clicks='"Converted_clicks[j]"',Revenue='"Total_Conv_value[j]);
}
```

Comment: 1/ quotes 2/ sql injection 3/ misuse. Please read on [prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560021/sql-injection-how-to-use-preparedstatement-in-java)

Comment: see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Can we use SET keyword in INSERT statement? I never used, SET is for UPDATE statement and for INSERT statement there is a VALUES keyword.

Comment: Aside from the misuse of prepared statements, what dbms are you using and what error are you getting? It looks like you're using the syntax `INSERT INTO table SET column  = value` which IIRC is completely wrong.

Comment: already they had developed this code in R language. now I need to convert it into Java to run as batch files. In R language, they used this SQL commands. Sql command is common for all languages .so I had used it here for insertion and update

Comment: There is no `SET` keyword for the `INSERT` statement in SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Three main problems there:

1. You're not using quotes where you should be using quotes.
2. I'm not aware of any database that uses an `INSERT ... SET` statement.
3. You're leaving yourself wide open to SQL Injection attacks.

Obligatory comic re #3:

[image]

Instead:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO sampletable " +
    "(FirstColumn SecondColumn, Etc) " +
    "VALUES " +
    "(?, ?, ?)"
);
pst.setString(1, "value for first column");
pst.setInt(2, 42);
pst.setDate(3, /*...some date...*/);
pst.execute();
```

The question marks are placeholders where the prepared statement will put the values. Even when the parameter is a string, you don't put quotes around the question mark; that's handled behind the scenes and is part of the reason for using prepared statements. Note that the parameter numbers start at 1, not 0.

Read up on SQL syntax and how to correctly use prepared statements; [this site](http://bobby-tables.com/java.html) may be useful.

Comment: okay. for insertion ,i knew this command .Actually the table has two columns as primary key .now i need to overwrite the data presented in the primary key ROW.how it's possible. for example : data assumed as              dane,223-456-4211,11/2/2015,35, 45 ,2345                                                  in this statement 2nd and 3rd column values are primary key. remaining 25,35,2345 values will be changed daily .i need to update that value daily by using program

Comment: @abhilash.r: You do that using an `UPDATE` statement. Read up on SQL.